# Otro proceso git parece estar corriendo en el repositorio, es decir un editor abierto con 'git commit'

Tags: git, git-commit

Intenté hacer un `git commit -a` y lo detuve. Al volver a hacer `git add .` no me deja y me sale este error:

> Otro proceso git parece estar corriendo en el repositorio, es decir
> un editor abierto con 'git commit'. Por favor asegúrese de que todos los procesos están terminados y vuelve a intentar. Si el fallo permanece, un proceso git puede haber roto el repositorio antes: borra el archivo manualmente para continuar.

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta eliminar el fichero de bloqueo:

```
rm -f .git/index.lock
```

La existencia de este fichero hace que no puedas hacer otras acciones de git mientras exista.

Comment: muchas gracias <3